# A way to spread user credentials without manually adding them to each computer

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10, network-shares, credentials

Say you have a shared network drive, it requires user and password authentication to access its contents.

User and password can be added to a single PC, via net use command or Windows Credentials Manager and it is granted access to the drive.

All the computers and the drive are on the same network and they all can access provided they have the credentials.

I have also tried creating copies of my own Windows Credentials, since a copy can be restored on another PC, but it still has to be done manually, I need to find a way to do this automatically.

How can you ***spread*** such credentials to say 100 PCs, without having to add them one by one?

Is it possible to use **net use** on specific devices since we know their IPs?

Most of the computers are in a domain. A single user was created with specific permissions granted and all the computers are expected to use its credentials to work with the resource.

Comment: 1) Are the computers in a domain?  2) Given the serious lack of security this approach involves, is there a specific reason you don't grant the `Everyone` identity access to the shared resource?

Comment: The users need to be in the authenticated users list on the shared drive/folder to gain access without entering credentials. Right click on the drive/folder you want to be shared, security tab/sharing tab and add the user to the permissions list. Next time they go to it, they won't have to enter credentials?

Comment: @Twisty Impersonator: most of the computers are in a domain. A single user was created, with specific permissions granted, and all the computers are expected to use its credentials to work with the resource. Are you saying it perhaps should allow everyone instead?

Comment: @Narzard: I have not tried yet to add users manually to the shared resource, will this allow access to everyone that needs to access without having to do anything on every computer?

Comment: @user1676874 I'm glad they're in a domain. This is easily done in a domain. You should create a security group, grant **it** access to the resource, then make all the users who need access members of that group. That's the correct way to do what you're trying.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I see, I will try this tomorrow, I too hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

## Shared credentials are insecure and difficult to manage

As you've discovered, securely granting multiple users access to a resource using a single user account is problematic. I explain at the end of this answer what makes this difficult and why it should be avoided.

But first, the correct way to grant access to a resource is by using individual user accounts for each user that needs access. How you do this will differ for the machines that are part of the target resource host's domain and those that are not.

### Same-domain members

For users that access the resource from machines that are in the same domain as the computer that hosts the resource, you simply need to grant access to the existing AD user accounts that need access.
The best-practice method is as follows:

1. Create a domain security group.
2. Grant the group access to the target resource.
3. Make each AD user object that needs access to the resource a member of the security group.

### Non-domain members

For users that need access to the resource but from machines that are not in the resource's domain, the best practice method is still to grant access to individual user accounts as follows:

1. Create Active Directory user accounts using the **same** usernames and passwords used to log on the non-domain computers that require access to the resource.

   If for some reason you don't have access to the users' passwords, then alternately you may either:

   a. Create AD user accounts for each non-domain user and assign a password of your choosing. In this case you should specify usernames that are *different* than that used on the non-domain computer, otherwise the username will match but the password won't, blocking successful logon. (Preferred.)

   b. Create a single AD user object that will be shared by all non-domain users. (Not preferred--see below.)
2. Make the new AD users object(s) members of the group you created in step #1 in the section above.

---

### Why avoid a single user object when granting access to multiple users?

As you can see the best-practice approach avoids using a single username and password to grant access to the resource.  There are several reasons for this:

- **Shared accounts are inflexible for changing access requirements.** When it comes time to revoke a user's access, a shared account is unforgiving. You must change the password on the account, which requires changing it on all devices that still require access, leading to...
- **Shared passwords are labor-intensive to change.** We assume you're using the password to keep certain users out, making a password change inevitable. But instead of changing the password on one device, you must change it on many devices, most of which are often non-centrally managed. To make matters worse, until the new password is deployed, devices using the old password cannot access the resource.
- **Shared accounts don't identify authorized users.**  Nowhere in the system will you have visibility into who has access via the shared account. You (and whomever else manages the environment) will need to maintain a separate list. And unlike when granting authorization directly to user objects, there's no *guarantee* the external list is accurate. Further, when real-time monitoring access to the resource, a shared account doesn't reveal who's actually using the resource.
- **Shared accounts are more exposed to compromise.**  They get used by more people from more places on more systems, each representing a possible point of compromise. Refer back to issue #1 for the difficulty involved in remedying this with a password change.

### Mass-Distributing a Single Logon Credential

Perhaps you find that you must still employ a shared username and password to grant access to the resource.  If you find yourself in this case, the bad news is that there's no way to conveniently distribute it in an automated fashion that maintains any semblance of security.

The primary problem for automation is the fact it's necessary to use/save the shared credential *in the logon context of the user accessing the resource*. This rules out any remote automation processes (unless you know each user's password, in which case you don't need to use a shared credential).

All that's left is to access the computers one-by-one while the user is present so they can be logged in while you store the shared credential, or to provide the credential directly to the users so they can enter it themselves.